# What happens when someone leaves a Recursion?

Tags: the-strange

When you do the translation into a Recursion, as far as I understand, you turn yourself into "another person" (same memory, different foci), but for people in the world (even those with Spark and Quickened), you're someone who has "always existed" there.

The question is:

If you leave the Recursion, is your existence on it "erased"? If so, is it "brought back" when you return? If not, how would the absence be explained? Do you receive memories from your existence in there when you're not there?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't have my book at hand ATM, but the explanation is that, only those with the Spark would even remember that you had been there and would notice the absense.  Most natives of the recusion simply "accept" your presence while you're there, and "accept" your absence (or, rather, pay it no mind).

If it makes it easier, think of the non-Sparky natives as simple creations in a Star Trek Holodeck(tm), with only a basic AI (they keep to the same storyline, all the time); while those with the Spark are "living" creations, able to interact and react to the "visitors" in a more normalized manner.

Comment: I will only disagree with your comparison. People in a recursion are very alive, they simply haven't been *sparked* like player characters. I believe you could even have children with non-sparked people.

Comment: For reference, there is a short story (from *Tales of the Strange* i believe) about a character who "wakes up" after seeing a recursion team in action.

Comment: Thanks... I didn't understand this first time I've read

Comment: @ShadowKras I also don't have the book at hand, but my recollection agrees with RWL. People without the Spark are not self-aware, thinking beings -- until they awaken (which most **can't**). I recall discussing them with another GM and we eventually concluded that killing them was distasteful, but not technically murder.
Having children with non-sparked people is also really distasteful.
(Also having children who themselves do not have the spark is possible, and it is one of the saddest things that game contains)

Comment: @ShadowKras And in that same story, if you recall, she _was not aware_ of her differences _until_ she gained the Spark.  Until that moment, she existed as part of the recursion, going about her recursion-assigned tasks _literally_ **mindlessly**.

Comment: Oh, don't get me wrong, I agree with *most* of the answer. It is simply the star trek reference that might mislead readers that won't delve into the fictions as we have.